# Norm inequality for a tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let $a,b \in H_1$ and $c,d \in H_2$ where $H_1, H_2$ are Hilbert spaces. Denote $H = H_1 \otimes H_2$. Can we then bound
$|| a \otimes c - b \otimes d ||^2_H$ in terms of $||a-b||^2_{H_1}$ and $||c-d||^2_{H_2}$?

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following bound to be helpful:
\begin{align}
\|a \otimes c - b \otimes d\| &= 
\|(a \otimes c - a \otimes d) + (a \otimes d - b \otimes d)\|
\\ & \leq
\|a \otimes(c-d)\| + \|(a-b) \otimes d\|
\\ &= \|a\|_{H_1} \|c-d\|_{H_2} + \|a-b\|_{H_1}\|d\|_{H_2}.
\end{align}
With a similar derivation, we can also get the upper bound
$$
\|a \otimes c - b \otimes d\| \leq \|c\|_{H_2} \|a-b\|_{H_1} + \|b\|_{H_1} \|c-d\|_{H_2}.
$$